# How to only keep rows in python dataframe with column value in a list?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to keep all rows where the value in one of the columns is in a list. (or if you want delete the rows where the value in a columns is not in the list.

In the df['ID'] column there is a large number of ID's and they occur several times. There are only some of them that i want to keep. Those ID's are kept as strings in a list called surv3.

I tried this:

df = df.loc[(df['ID'] in surv3)]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isin` method.

For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['ga', 'bu', 'zo', 'meu']})
mylist = ['ga', 'meu']
```

`df[df.test.isin(mylist)]` returns:

```
test
0   ga
3   meu
```